# how to get cascading listboxes

Tags: asp.net

I have two listboxes on my page Say ListBox A and ListBox B.
I am populating data into ListBox A using generic lists.

I want to populate ListBox B based on ListBox A selection

Could someone please guide me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Cascading Drop Down](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) control in the ASP.NET AJAX Control toolkit. To change it from a drop down to a list box, place `multiple="true"` or `multiple="multiple"` in the attributes.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
But I need cascading list box and not Cascading Dropdown

Comment: I will test the change to a list box when i get the chance, there may be a problem with sending multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

i think all what you have to do is :

add the following event of ur listbox A

add this to your code behind

```
protected void ListBoxA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // populate listbox B
}
```

the following attribute to your listbox A in your aspx :

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxA" runat="server" 
onselectedindexchanged="ListBoxA_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxB" runat="server" 
></asp:ListBox>
```